# What did the Kinks make to get banned on the US?

Tags: rock

On their first tour on the US, the Kinks where banned for 6 years. I have looked up on the internet but the reasons are quite unclear. Does anyone know them?

Comment: Please expose your research, what did you find on internet (sources), what was unclear... so people won't say what you already know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two theories I found; both seem likely and it could be some combination of the two, but I bet not paying their dues was the cause more than the fighting.

1. They were notorious for on stage fighting with each other [1](https://99wfmk.com/kriminalkinks/) [2](https://rulefortytwo.com/secret-rock-knowledge/chapter-8/kinks-ban/) [3](https://ultimateclassicrock.com/kinks-in-america/)
2. They [failed to pay](https://rulefortytwo.com/secret-rock-knowledge/chapter-8/kinks-ban/) mandatory dues to the American Federation of Television and Recording Artists.